# Login con sessions php y fwrite?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un mini sistema de creacion de carpetas con archivos incluidos al crease.

Mi problema es el login donde no lo puedo hacer funcionar, el usuario al registarse crea la carpeta con los archivos. pero quiero que el nombre de la carpeta sea el usuario y la clave.

alguien me podria ayudar?

si el codigo lo estoy haciendo mal o tengo algo mal favor de decirme :(

codigo donde crea la carpeta con archivos

```html
<?php  
    $dirname = $_POST["name"];  
    $filename = "{$dirname}";  
    
    $file = 'public_html/iconos/menu-icono.png';
    $newfile = 'users/{$dirname}/iconos';   


    if (file_exists($filename)) {  
        echo "El nombre de usuario {$dirname} Ya existe";  
    } else {  
        mkdir("users/{$dirname}", 0777);
        mkdir("users/{$dirname}/archivos", 0777);
        mkdir("users/{$dirname}/perfil", 0777);
        mkdir("users/{$dirname}/css", 0777);
        mkdir("users/{$dirname}/iconos", 0777);     
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/datos.css", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/enviado.css", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/estilo.css", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/file.css", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/fotos.css", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/login.css", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/register.css", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/salir.css", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/css/sidebar.css", "w");


 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/index.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/archivo.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion_cambiar.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion_eliminararchivos.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/configuracion_fotoperfil.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/eliminararchivos.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/eliminarcuenta.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/eliminarfoto.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/enviado.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/login.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/panel.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/perfilcorrecto.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/salir.php", "w");
 $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/subir", "w");
    $fp = fopen("users/{$dirname}/validar.php", "w");
 fwrite($fp,$content); 
 fclose($fp); 
        echo "<p id='numero1'> Tu cuenta de {$dirname} Fue creado correctamente.</p>";
        echo "<p id='numero2'>Si desea acceder a su cuenta favor da <a href='users/{$dirname}'>Click aqui</a></p>.";    
    }


?>
```

codigo 2 donde es la validacion del login

```html
fp = fopen("users/${dirname}/validar.php", "w") or die("Error al intentar abrir el archivo!");
fwrite($fp, '<?php

$miuser = \'$_POST["name"]\';
$mipass = \'$_POST["address"]\';

if(isset($_POST[\'login\'])) {
    $usuario = $_POST[\'usuario\'];
    $pass = $_POST[\'password\'];
    if ($usuario == $miuser and $pass == $mipass ) {
        if (isset($_POST[\'remember\'])) {
            setcookie(\'usuario\', $usuario, time()+60*60*7);
            setcookie(\'passowrd\', $pass, time()+60*60*7);
        } 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[\'usuario\'] = $usuario;
        header(\'location:panel\');
    } else {
        echo \'<p>usuario o clave son incorrectos</p>\';
    }
} else {
    header(\'location: login\');
}

?>');
fwrite($fp,$miuser,$mipass); 
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` siempre tiene que estar por encima de todo. Comienzas con `<?php` sigues con `session_start();` y el resto del código. Así en todas los archivos en donde usas datos de usuarios registrados

Comment: Eso ya está pero en $miuser = \'$_POST["name"]\';
$mipass = \'$_POST["address"]\'; los datos que son me sale usuario o contraseña son incorrectos, el session_start ya está pero sale eso

Answer (score 0):

La contraseña no debería ser visible en ningún momento en tu sistema. No la uses para nombrar ficheros o carpetas en ningún caso. Ahora, los nombres de usuario deberán ser únicos si los usas para hacer un login o a efectos de algún tipo de identificación.

Veamos el código, he comentado las líneas que no funcionan o que sí lo hacen pero hacen cosas innecesarias:

Código 1:

```
<?php  
    $dirname  = $_POST["name"];  
    $filename = $dirname;
    // $filename = "{$dirname}"; // innecesaria

    $file = 'public_html/iconos/menu-icono.png';

    $newfile = "users/{$dirname}/iconos";
    // $newfile = 'users/{$dirname}/iconos'; // error de lógica no de PHP, no compones la ruta correctamente
```

El resto parece OK. Para el código 2, hay errores de sintaxis por todas partes, no va a compilar, veamos las primeras líneas

```
// ...

$miuser = $_POST["name"];
// $miuser = \'$_POST["name"]\'; // error sintaxis
$mipass = $_POST["address"];
// $mipass = \'$_POST["address"]\'; // error sintaxis

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
// if(isset($_POST[\'login\'])) { // error sintaxis
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    // $usuario = $_POST[\'usuario\']; // error sintaxis
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    // $pass = $_POST[\'password\']; // error sintaxis
```

Parece que tienes algunos problemas a la hora de manipular strings y arrays asociativos ($_POST). Revisa eso. A parte debes separar claramente las diferentes partes del sistema: login, generación de ficheros, los ficheros, etc.
Un saludo.